# Euler 17 Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is for project Euler problem #17, I'm attempting it in javascript. What's super weird to me is that if I call typeof() on my answer, it says it's a "number". Then if I try to run the function which prints the result I get "NaN"

If you know 1) a way to fix my code to work and/or 2) a more elegant way to attack this problem if one exists (I don't doubt that it does), constructive criticism is greatly appreciated!

```
var arrayOnes = [3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4];
var arrayTeens = [6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8];
var arrayTens = [3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6];
var arrayHundreds = [12,12,14,13,13,12,14,14,13];
var sum99 = 0;
var sum999 = 0;
var sum1000 = 11;

function sumsOneToNineNine() {
    for (i=1; i<=9; i++) {
        sum99 += ((arrayOnes[i]*9) + arrayTeens[i] + arrayTens[i]);
    }
}

function sumsOneToOneThousand() {
    sumsOneToNineNine();
    for (i=1; i<9; i++) {
    sum999 += arrayHundreds[i];
    }
    sum999 += 9*sum99 + sum999;
    sum1000 += sum999;
    console.log(sum1000);
}

sumsOneToOneThousand();
```

Comment: Well, `NaN` is a number value, according to the spec and the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: `NaN` is of a numeric type in *every* language. Why is it "so weird" in Javascript?

Comment: I just realized that it should be i-1 instead of i for each of my things, to account for indexes beginning at 0, not 1. Now I get a # answer but it's not the correct answer.

Comment: also just realized my arrayHundreds are all short by 1. still not getting correct answer.

Comment: plus I don't think I'm applying the one-hundred nearly enough. thanks, I think I can get it from here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you said you think you can get it, I figured I would post a slightly ***cleaner*** solution than you presented, that can also be pretty easily extended well past one thousand, even though the problem does not require it.

Anyway, the teens also have a pattern, where 5 of them are the same length as the name of the number + ten, due to a dropped letter, and the other 4, due to a letter not being dropped, are 1 letter *longer*.

Once you are past 100 up to 9,999 (and yes I know the problem doesn't need it, but if you wanted to extend it to persay, 10K), you can just re-use the ones place array, and then as you get into the 10K-100K range, reuse the teens rule and the tens place array, etc.

```
var lenHundred = 7;
var lenThousand = 8;
var lenPlaceOnes = [0,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4];
var lenPlaceTens = [0,3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6];

function sumTo(num) {
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        var placeOnes = i % 10;
        var placeTens = Math.floor(i / 10) % 10;
        var placeHundreds = Math.floor(i / 100) % 10;
        var placeThousands = Math.floor(i / 1000) % 10;

        // Add the ones place
        sum += lenPlaceOnes[placeOnes];

        // Add the tens place
        sum += lenPlaceTens[placeTens];

        // If the hundreds place is non-zero, add it and "hundred"
        if (placeHundreds != 0) {
            sum += lenHundred + lenPlaceOnes[placeHundreds];
        }

        // If the thousands place is non-zero, add it and "thousand"
        if (placeThousands != 0) {
            sum += lenThousand + lenPlaceOnes[placeThousands];
        }

        ////////////////
        // TEENS RULE //
        ////////////////

        // If the number is in the teens, take care of special numbers
        // Eleven is the same length as "oneten", Twelve the same as "twoten", and so on
        // With the exception of those in the switch statement
        if (placeTens == 1) {
            // If the ones place is 4, 6, 7, or 9, add an extra 1 for the "e"
            switch (placeOnes) {
                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 9:
                    sum += 1;
                    break;
            }
        }

        //////////////
        // AND RULE //
        //////////////

        // If the value is above one hundred, and the number is not an exact hundred, add
        // 3 for the "and"
        if (i > 100 && i % 100 != 0) {
            sum += 3;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

console.log("Sum to Five Inclusive: " + sumTo(5));
console.log("Sum to 1K Inclusive: " + sumTo(1000));
```